# replacement has 45781858 rows, data has 1752611

Tags: r

I think this was asked already before, but I cannot find a solution for my issue.
I have the following data frame

```
 (obj_1 <- data.frame (
      yr = c(1990, 1990, 1990, 1992, 1992, 1992),
      EARNWEEK= c(223, 200, 234, 500, 700, 800),
      AHRSWORKT= c(50, 40, 35, 35, 35, 40),
      WAGE = c(10, 8, 8, 9, 10, 9)
   ))
```

I would like created a column named REALWAGE, where I insert in each row the value of the variable WAGE multiplied by a value, which differs across the years. As I try to run the following code ...

```
obj1[obj1$yr %in% 1992,"REALWAGE"] <- cps_data$WAGE*1.223
```

and so on for the next year

```
obj1[obj1$yr %in% 1993,"REALWAGE"] <- cps_data$WAGE*1.153
```

... the error  `replacement has 45781858 rows, data has 1752611` is getting displayed. How is it possible to fix that?

Many thanks in advance!!

Comment: What do `nrow(cps_data)` and `sum(obj1$yr %in% 1992)` output?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You have to subset on both sides:

```
i <- obj_1$yr == 1992
obj_1[i,"REALWAGE"] <- obj_1$WAGE[i]*1.223
```

Or you use a lookup table using `match`

```
LU <- read.table(text="
1992 1.223
1993 1.153")

obj_1$REALWAGE <- obj_1$WAGE * LU[match(obj_1$yr, LU[,1]), 2]
```

or

```
LU <- c('1992' = 1.223, '1993' = 1.153)
obj_1$REALWAGE <- obj_1$WAGE * LU[as.character(obj_1$yr)]
```

Answer (score 1):

You can first construct a dictionary data frame `dic`, e.g.,

```
dic <- data.frame(yr = c(1990, 1991, 1992), f = c(1.011, 1.223, 1.153))
```

and then use `merge` + `transform`

```
transform(
  merge(obj_1, dic, all.x = TRUE),
  REALWAGE = WAGE * f
)
```

such that

```
    yr EARNWEEK AHRSWORKT WAGE     f REALWAGE
1 1990      223        50   10 1.011   10.110
2 1990      200        40    8 1.011    8.088
3 1990      234        35    8 1.011    8.088
4 1992      500        35    9 1.153   10.377
5 1992      700        35   10 1.153   11.530
6 1992      800        40    9 1.153   10.377
```

Answer (score 0):

We can also do a join with a `keyval` dataset in `data.table`

```
library(data.table)
setDT(obj_1)[keyval, REALWAGE := WAGE * f, on = .(yr)]
```

#### data

```
keyval <- data.frame(yr = c(1990, 1991, 1992), f = c(1.011, 1.223, 1.153))
```

Answer (score -1):

I just saw that the two codes above don't work. These are the right ones!

```
obj_1[obj_1$yr %in% 1992,"REALWAGE"] <- obj_1$WAGE*1.223

obj_1[obj_1$yr %in% 1993,"REALWAGE"] <- obj_1$WAGE*1.153
```